# In Ionic, how to set ion-slides autoHeight to true with ion-content scrollable?

Tags: ionic-framework, swiper.js

I'd like the slider to adapt its size according to active slide height.

There's an option autoHeight:true but it's not working

```
options:
{
 autoHeight:true
}
```

It works only if ion-content scroll is set to false

Comment: hi! i have the same situation here, did you found a solution for this?

Comment: I ended up with another solution but you could try to put the slider inside another ion-content... never tried it but I think I saw that somewhere.

Comment: thanks for your answer, i already do this, i have two ion-contents, in the second is my ion-slides, but it is always 100% of the visibile screen, so you cant see the paginations on bottom :(

Answer (score 0):

I'm able to make swiper in ionic to have auto height size with this css

```
.swiper-wrapper {
  position: relative;  
}
```

and my options is just the default options shown in ionic documentation

```
vm.options = {
  loop: true,
  effect: 'fade',
  speed: 500,
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Base on [this](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/dynamic-slide-height/63891/35?u=moshequ), you can add the following css:

```
.swiper-slide:not(.swiper-slide-active) > div {
  display:none;
}
```

I've tested it and it works fine.